# asp.net-mvc2 - Controller not taking area into account when returning View()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, view, asp.net-mvc-areas

When calling `return View()` in a controller that resides in an area it tries to locate the views in the main `~/Views/{Controller}/` folder and the main `~/Views/Shared/` folder. It doesn't look in the `~/{Area}/Views/{Controller}/` folder.

I tried adding a routevalue for `area` to the `MapRoute` function and also tried adding a 'datatoken' for "area" to the Route's `DataTokens` property.

Am I missing something here?

This is the `MapRoute` call:

```
routes.MapRoute("Product", "Products/{GroupName}/{CategoryId}/{CategoryName}/{ProductId}/{ProductName}/{PageName}", New With {.Area = "Products", .controller = "Products", .action = "Product", .PageName = ""}, New With {.CategoryId = "[0-9]*", .ProductId = "[0-9]*"})
```

Comment: Can you post your MapRoute function?

Comment: I've added the call to MapRoute

Comment: Check that the AreaName overridden is same as the path of Area folder in global application.

Comment: @kaps: `AreaName`? I'm only passing `area`. Where does the `AreaName` come into play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi general stuff to look at:

Have you registered area mapping and area mapping?
have you same name for controller in both locations?

Example of area mapping in global.asax

see line :  AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();  //  This is part you neeed to do

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );

}

protected void Application_Start()
{

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();  //  This is part you neeed to do
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory());
}
```

}

and every area has to have mapping or mapping file somewhere set up.
Example here

namespace Project
{
    /// 
    /// Registration of administration area
    /// 
    public class AdministratorAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        /// 
        /// Gets the name of the area to be registered.
        /// 
        /// The name of the area to be registered.
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "Administrator";
            }
        }

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Registers an area in an ASP.NET MVC application using the specified area's context information.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">Encapsulates the information that is required in order to register the area.</param>
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Administrator_default",
            "Administrator/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }
}
```

}

if you have problem with the routing check this.

I would recomend to use this guide, and create tests for every routing:
http://haacked.com/archive/2007/12/17/testing-routes-in-asp.net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As we usually do with Areas, we add an AeaRegistraion file (FooAreaRegistration.cs) and override AreaName and RegisterArea() method. AreaName we set to the relative path of the folder where AearRegistration file resides with respect to the global application. Following is example.

```
public class FooAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the Area Name
    /// </summary>
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get { return "ParentApp/AreaFolder"; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Map and Route the area
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        if (null != context)
        {
            //context.maproute goes here              
        }            
    }
}
```